# Converting from JSONArray to String then back again

Tags: java, android, string, json

I need to store a JSONArray object as a string then retrieve the string and convert it back to a JSONArray.

If I do:

```
JSONArray jArray;
String s = jArray.toString()
JSONArray newJArray = new JSONArray(s);
```

Will I get back the same object?

I'm trying to store a JSONArray in a SQLite database.

Here's what I'm looking at. [http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString%28%29)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As long as it's a valid JSONArray to begin with, then yes.