# android how to convert json array to string array

Tags: android, json

I have an app where I fetch data from server(json) in the form of array & by using the index i used in my app, like below.

```
JSONObject topobj = new JSONObject(page);
JSONObject innerobj = topobj.getJSONObject("restarutant");
JSONArray phone = innerobj.getJSONArray("phone");
textViewPhone.setText("Phone: " + phone.get(0).toString() + " ,"
                    + phone.get(1).toString());
```

for small size array I can get like this. But when array contains 'n' no of elements and dynamically i have to use this, at that time it required to convert into String Array.
Can anybody tell me how I convert the json array to String array ?
Thank you

Comment: you should accept correct answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Json Array to normal Java Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array)

Comment: ArrayList is not a String[] , title wont fulfill  your explanation of question AND the accepted answer it for ArrayList , NOT String[]  ;

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983932/converting-from-jsonarray-to-string-then-back-again) should help you.

Edit:

Maybe this is what you need:

```
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hiii,my question is different. Its for coverting objecty to string then string to json array. But I asked to convert json array to string array

Comment: The title is about String[] , but the accepted answer gives a ArrayList<String> , Which are totally different however

Answer (score 6):

Assume that you already have JSONArray jsonArray:

```
String[] stringArray = new stringArray[jsonArray.length()];
for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
{
    try {
        String jsonString = jsonArray.getString(i);
        stringArray[i] = jsonString.toString();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: new stringArray[jsonArray.length()]; 
--- should be --->
new String[jsonArray.length()];

Answer (score 5):

This I think is what you searching for

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jsonArray != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){ 
    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just did this yesterday!  If you're willing to use a 3rd party library then you can use [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), with the additional benefit of having more concise code.

```
String json = jsonArray.toString();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<String>>(){}.getType();
Collection<String> strings = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);

for (String element : strings)
{
    Log.d("TAG", "I'm doing stuff with: " + element);
}
```

You can find more examples in the [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant kotlin way:

```
val list = jsonArray.map { jsonElement -> jsonElement.toString() }
```

And just convert to array if needed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `org.json` package, Here is the kotlin way of converting json array to string array.

```
// get json array
val jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("field")
// convert to string array
val stringArray = Array(jsonArray.length()) { jsonArray.getString(it) }
```