# How to display json formatted data in android

Tags: android, json

I have this data from api in json format and now I want to display it in my android app. How can I do that?

```
{  
  "error":false,
  "response_code":200,
  "train_name":"NZM GARIB RATH",
  "from_station":{  
    "name":"BANDRA TERMINUS",
    "code":"BDTS"
  },
  "reservation_upto":{  
    "name":"H NIZAMUDDIN",
    "code":"NZM"
  },
  "pnr":"8459527593",
  "boarding_point":{  
    "name":"BANDRA TERMINUS",
    "code":"BDTS"
  },
  "passengers":[  
    {  
      "no":1,
      "booking_status":"W/L 77,GNWL",
      "current_status":"W/L 38"
    }
  ],
  "train_num":"12909",
  "chart_prepared":"N",
  "total_passengers":1,
  "doj":"28-7-2015",
  "to_station":{  
    "name":"H NIZAMUDDIN",
    "code":"NZM"
  },
  "class":"3A"
}
```

Comment: please edit ur question ... this is not acceptable!!!!

Comment: Before posting do google ur question ....

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow,

1. Create a HttpURLConnection or URLConnection and make a GET/POST request to the url which will return the response.
2. Receive the JSON response as an Entity and convert it into String.
3. Make a JSON object from the response string.
4. Create a loop and parse all JSON data.
5. Create your custom list adapter and put the parsed data into the array.

Reference:

[How do I use the Simple HTTP client in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/how-do-i-use-the-simple-http-client-in-android)

[how to parse JSONArray in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

[Android Custom ListView with Images and Text – Example](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)

Comment: HTTPClient is deprecated, better use HttpURLConnection or URLConnection