# how I can access data from a JSONArray in Android?

Tags: android, json, string

how I can access data from a `JSONArray`? It is this and contains this information:

```
"deadlines": [
{
    "start": 1439539200,
    "end": 1439542800
},
{
    "start": 1440144000,
    "end": 1440147600
},
{
    "start": 0,
    "end": 0
}
]
```

I need to have in a `String` tag each item `"start"`. Thanks

**EDIT**

My code is this:

```
JSONArray array = moduleObject.specialForcedConf;
// array = [{"deadlines":[{"start":1439539200,"end":1439542800},{"start":1440144000,"end":1440147600},{"start":0,"end":0}]}]

                    for (int j=0; j < array.length(); j++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(j);
                            String start = obj.getString("start"); 
                            String end = obj.getString("end"); 

                            Log.e("", "start = " + start);
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            Log.e("", "error = " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
```

I get this error:

```
"error = No value for start"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: It seems you'll find an answer to a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android). Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
JSONArray array = moduleObject.specialForcedConf;
// array = [{"deadlines":[{"start":1439539200,"end":1439542800},{"start":1440144000,"end":1440147600},{"start":0,"end":0}]}]

JSONArray jArray = array.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("deadlines");
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) // assuming your array is jArray
{
    try 
    {
        JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String start= obj.getString("start"); // store in an ArrayList
        String end = obj.getString("end");  //// store in an ArrayList
    }
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(yourjsondata));
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jo_feed = new JSONObject(ja.get(i).toString());
    String start = jo_feed.getString("start");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("deadlines");
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

  JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

  sb.append(obj.get("start").toString());

  sb.append(",");

}

String strStartTag = sb;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray mJsonArray=new JSONArray("Deadlines");

for(int i=0;i<mJsonArray.length();i++){
 JSONObject mJsonObject=new JSONObject(mJsonArray.get(i).toString));
 String start = mJsonObject.optString("start",""); 
 String end = mJsonObject.optString("end",""); 
}
```