# How to parse a json array within a json object in android

Tags: android, json

Following is the `JSON response` i have got from a web service. I want to parse it in an android app:

```
{"text":["Gayatri Hari Mankar","Prajaval V. Kakade","ram  joshi","Revati R Sharma","Sneha M Verma","Sumeet N Wankar"],"status":1000}
```

I want to retrieve all the names under the `text array`.

Its a different case than that of the one mentioned below. [how to parse JSONArray in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

Comment: @Vishwa --its a json response sir i have hit the service through a rest client and i got this response. Its a valid one because it has curly braces and square braces also. Anyways thanks for your response!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse JSONArray in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just simple parsing of array with variable length.

```
JSONObject wholeObject = new JSONObject(); //add your response here, from string for example
JSONArray textArray = wholeObject.getJSONArray("text");
for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length(); i++) {
    Log.d("text", textArray.getString(i) );
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot... Only you have to put  textArray.length() instead of textArray.size() and thats it!

Comment: Whoops, I was typing from memory. I'll edit that, thanks for warning.

Comment: Anyways but poss you rocks :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept the answer to get it out of unanswered queue

Comment: There is a check under a number to mark the answer as "solved my problem" basically.