# how to access an element of an JSON array

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Given below is my JSON and I want to access **"trips"** JSON array and want to place it in an array list so that I can use it in a spinner. How can I access trips JSON array directly and use as a ArrayList for spinner?

My JSON:

```
        {
            "trips": [
                77
            ],
            "status": {
            "message": "Successfully fetched the Open trips ",
            "code": 200
            }
        }
```

My Activity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ArrayList<String> trips;
    private JSONArray result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        trips= new ArrayList<String>();
        this.spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        loadtrip();
    }
    public void loadtrip() {
        HashMap<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
        {
            params.put("systemId", "12");
            params.put("customerId", "3513");
            params.put("userId", "124");
            params.put("tripType", "Open");
        }
        JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,config.DATA_URL,  new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            result = response.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,trips));
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }) ;
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


    }
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? is what's the return value of your `result`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse JSONArray in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can get value from json array directly from its index.

```
JSONArray array = yourJsonObject.getJSONArray("trips");
    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        int value = array.getInt(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    JSONArray array = yourJsonObject.getJSONArray("trips");
    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) 
    {
        int value = array.getInt(i);
    }
   JSONObject objStates = yourJsonObject.getJSONObject(“status”);
   String msg= objStates.getString(“message”)
   Int code= objStates.getInt(“code”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
  try {
         result = response.getJSONArray("trips");
         for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++){
                trips.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(i)));
         } 
  } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `int value;` and parse `JSON`:

```
 new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
   try {
    result = response.getJSONArray("trips");
    for (int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {
    value = result.getInt(i);
    trips.add(String.valueOf(value));
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,trips));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using config.JSON_ARRAY key to parse in your code, what is the value for config.JSON_ARRAY. If config.JSON_ARRAY="trips" then fine and replace static "trips" key with yours config.JSON_ARRAY else follow mine static key to parse.

Just update your code with this one: In this I parsed the trips JSON array and added all the items to the trips ArrayList.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener {
        private Spinner spinner;
        private ArrayList<String> trips;
        private JSONArray result;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            trips= new ArrayList<String>();
            this.spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            loadtrip();
        }
        public void loadtrip() {
            trips = new ArrayList<>();

            HashMap<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
            {
                params.put("systemId", "12");
                params.put("customerId", "3513");
                params.put("userId", "124");
                params.put("tripType", "Open");
            }
            JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,config.DATA_URL,  new JSONObject(params),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                result = response.optJSONArray("trips");
                                for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++){
                                    trips.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(i)));
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,trips));
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                    }) ;
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me.

```
    JSONObject object = jObj.getJSONObject(result);

    Iterator<?> iterator = object.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) iterator.next();
        ArrayList<JSONObject> value = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray(key);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            value.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
        }

        System.out.println("key : " + key + " " + "value : " + value);
        hm.put(key, value);
    }
```