# how can i read this nested jsonarray to ArrayList<Class> or ArrayList<Hashmap>

Tags: android

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"z1",
      "assigned_rsm":[  
         {  
            "id":"r1",
            "assigned_asm":[  
               {  
                  "id":"a1",
                  "assigned_se":[  
                     {  
                        "id":"se1",
                        "lat":"17.0398825",
                        "lng":"81.810038"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":"se2",
                        "lat":"17.0646295",
                        "lng":"81.8464776"
                     }
                  ],
                  "lat":"16.9986757",
                  "lng":"81.7822002"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"a2",
                  "assigned_se":[  
                     {  
                        "id":"se3",
                        "lat":"17.0692217",
                        "lng":"81.8585722"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":"se4",
                        "lat":"17.0113276",
                        "lng":"81.7878182"
                     }
                  ],
                  "lat":"16.9969446",
                  "lng":"81.784208"
               }
            ],
            "lat":"17.1137574",
            "lng":"81.8565959"
         },
         {  
            "id":"r2",
            "assigned_asm":[  
               {  
                  "id":"a3",
                  "assigned_se":[  
                     {  
                        "id":"se5",
                        "lat":"17.0092473",
                        "lng":"81.7815832"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":"se6",
                        "lat":"17.0090579",
                        "lng":"81.8464776"
                     }
                  ],
                  "lat":"16.9986757",
                  "lng":"81.7822002"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"a4",
                  "assigned_se":[  
                     {  
                        "id":"se7",
                        "lat":"17.0076268",
                        "lng":"81.7709332"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":"se8",
                        "lat":"17.0165181",
                        "lng":"81.7765434"
                     }
                  ],
                  "lat":"16.9969446",
                  "lng":"81.784208"
               }
            ],
            "lat":"17.0444971",
            "lng":"81.8079411"
         },
         {  
            "id":"r3",
            "assigned_asm":[  
               {  
                  "id":"a5",
                  "assigned_se":[  
                     {  
                        "id":"se9",
                        "lat":"17.0184916",
                        "lng":"81.7739651"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":"se10",
                        "lat":"17.0216008",
                        "lng":"81.7746821"
                     }
                  ],
                  "lat":"16.9986757",
                  "lng":"81.7822002"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"a6",
                  "assigned_se":[  
                     {  
                        "id":"se11",
                        "lat":"17.0090165",
                        "lng":"81.8235776"
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":"se12",
                        "lat":"17.0454414",
                        "lng":"81.8381624"
                     }
                  ],
                  "lat":"16.9969446",
                  "lng":"81.784208"
               }
            ],
            "lat":"17.0301781",
            "lng":"81.8297379"
         }
      ],
      "lat":"17.0015486",
      "lng":"81.7945959"
   }
]
```

Comment: Use Gson library to parse response with models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse JSONArray in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Model, you should use the GSON library.

Otherwise, you can refer to this: [Convert Json Array to normal Java Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array)