# ArrayList of Strings to JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have an ArrayList that contains values as follows

```
"One"
"Two"
"Three" etc.
```

I am trying to generate an JSON Object / Array out of this. My code is below:

```
peopleNames = personAdapter.getArrayListNames();
peoplePhones= personAdapter.getArrayListPhones();

JSONNames = new JSONObject();
JSONPhones =  new JSONObject();

for (int i = 0; i < peopleNames.size(); i++){
    try {
        System.out.println(peopleNames.get(i));
        JSONNames.put("Name",peopleNames.get(i));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < peoplePhones.size(); i++){
    try {
        JSONPhones.put("Phone",peoplePhones.get(i));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

jsonArrayNames = new JSONArray();
System.out.println(jsonArrayNames.toString());
```

However my output is just:

```
[{"Name":"One"}]
```

Comment: Try using a ``JSONArray`` instead of a ``JSONObject``. Currently you overwrite the ``Name`` entry because you use ``put``.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: What is your problem? The data has been added to JSON

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you merge the data ? I think, from your adapter, you're able to get people directly, right ? If so, I propose you the following :

```
people = personAdapter.getPersons();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("Name", people.name());
    object.put("Phone", people.phone());
    jsonArray.put(object);
}
```

The resulted JSON will be :

```
[
  {"Name":"One",
   "Phone": "OnePhone"},
  {"Name":"Two",
   "Phone": "TwoPhone"},
]
```