# How to get the json array

Tags: android

I want the array of custac from the given json data. But I dont know how to call custac from that. I want to get the custac values in an array. can anyone help
Here is my code

```
ArrayList<CustomerPayment> customerPayments = new 
ArrayList<CustomerPayment>();
try {
    JSONArray resultVal = response.getJSONArray("Data");

    int count=resultVal.length();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        CustomerPayment payment = new CustomerPayment(resultVal.getJSONObject(i));
        customerPayments.add(payment);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my jsondata

```
Result: {
    "Result": {
        "Status": 200,
        "Success": true,
        "Reason": "OK"
    },
    "Data": [
        {
            "CustomerID": "PTM_103",
            "FirstName": "Dhanya",
            "LastName": "Jacob ",
            "NickName": "",
            "FundAmount": 440,
            "custac": [
                {
                    "AccountTrackingId": "prod_4",
                    "ReferenceID": "",
                    "CustomerID": "PTM_103",
                    "OrderID": "ae3208287743908eb8e5911d8e7e73df",
                    "orderAmount": "0",
                    "CreatedAt": "prod"
                }
            ]
    },
    ...
```

Comment: @AbhayBohra Can you please explain

Comment: inside the loop use resultVal.get(i).getJSONArray("custac");

Comment: @SRM firstly, please check your JSON, it's invalid response

Comment: @Nero Yes its correct..I have copied some only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse JSONArray in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

you have to make something like this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

JSONArray resultVal = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON data are objects parsed into a string for mostly NoSQL purposes and they can be parsed into objects. [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is one of the libraries which is easy to use to parse your JSON data.

If you get `jsonData` as the response string which has `Data`, the following code can parse the `custac` in the list of array. But, firstly you have to create an object for `Data`

```
Data[] dataCollection = new Gson().fromJson(json,Data[].class);
```

`Data` must contain the attributes like `CustomerID`, `FirstName`, etc.

For your case,

```
class Data{
    private String CustomerID;
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String NickName;
    private int FundAmount;
    private ArrayList<Custac> custac;
    class Custac{
        // Write your attributes as shown above.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
JSONArray custac;
 try {

    JSONArray resultVal = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");
    for (int i = 0; i < resultVal.length() - 1; i++) {
        jsonObject = resultVal.getJSONObject(i);
        custac = jsonObject.getJSONArray("custac");

        Log.d("TAG, custac + "");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```