# How do you parse json object inside a json array?

Tags: android, json, rx-android, android-json

I am pretty weak with `JSON`, and probably have a silly question, and was wondering how to parse a `JSON` object placed inside a `JSON` array.
So, as of now, I have

```
public Single<Profile> doProfileApiCall() {
        return Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(ApiEndPoint.ENDPOINT_PROFILE)
                .addHeaders(mApiHeader.getProtectedApiHeader())
                .build()
                .getObjectSingle(Profile.class);
```

To retrieve my profile params, but in my endpoints I have :

```
[{"Name": "this", "Email","that@gmail.com"}]
```

I have my endpoint set up as :

```
 public static final String ENDPOINT_PROFILE =
            BuildConfig.BASE_URL
            + "/linktojson";
```

which gives me the above `JSON`.
but the issue is the [], how do I modify this with :

```
 public Single<Profile> doProfileApiCall() {
            return Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(ApiEndPoint.ENDPOINT_PROFILE)
                    .addHeaders(mApiHeader.getProtectedApiHeader())
                    .build()
                    .getObjectSingle(Profile.class);
```

such that I can use my profile.java model class which has

```
public class Profile {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("Email")
    private String email;
    etc...
}
```

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: I think what you have there is a JSONArray with a single JSONObject in, i believe that this question might be of some help to you. [parse JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

Comment: cant i use : Rx2AndroidNetworking.post ? my array will grow soon and profile.java model class will consist of more json objects but all be within 1 array

Comment: Are you using the retrofit library for making API requests? If not can you specify the library name which you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In the doProfileApiCall() method instead of .getObjectSingle use

```
.getJSONArraySingle(ProfileList.class)
```

Now create a new class ProfileList.java with the following code.

```
List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Profile> getProfileList() {
    return profileList;
}

public void setProfileList(List<Profile> profileList) {
    this.profileList = profileList;
}
```

Change the returntype of the doProfileApiCall method to

```
public Single<ProfileList> doProfileApiCall()
```

Whenever you want to access the data use it with the list position 0, when in future you get more data, you can index the data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if `JSON` root object is an `array` you should use `List` on `Java` side. In your case you have `array` so use related method:

```
return Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(ApiEndPoint.ENDPOINT_PROFILE)
          .addHeaders(mApiHeader.getProtectedApiHeader())
          .build()
          .getObjectListSingle(Profile.class);
```

[`Rx2ANRequest`](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/blob/master/rx2-android-networking/src/main/java/com/rx2androidnetworking/Rx2ANRequest.java) source.

Comment: I get the error : Incompatible types. Required Single<Profile> but 'getObjectListSingle' was inferred to Single<List<T>>: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to Profile

Comment: @MarissaNicholas You can use map like so

`getObjectListSingle(Person.class)
.map(list -> list.get(0)`

Comment: still throws an error like "expected begin_object" but was a STRING at line 1 column 1 path 0

Comment: @MarissaNicholas, it means that `JSON` payload which is returned from sever is invalid. Could you show your `JSON` which you received?

Comment: [{"Name": "this", "Email","that@gmail.com"}]
 this is the json i receive

Comment: @MarissaNicholas, but exception clearly says `but was STRING`. There must be other white character or `"`. Your `JSON` payload should be `[{"Name": "this", "Email":"that@gmail.com"}]` - semicolon not comma between `"Email"` and `"that..."`. Have you posted with mistake or it is real payload?