# Android - JSON Parsing to custom ArrayList

Tags: android, json

Well, I want to parse JSON code to my custom ArrayList which has title and description parameters.

```
[
   {
        "title" : "title1",
        "description" : "desc1"
    },
    {  
        "title" : "title2",
        "description" : "desc2"
    }
 ]
```

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Model> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(new JSONObject(jsonString).getJSONArray(jsonString);

for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++)
{
     JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

String title = jo.getString("title");
String desc = jo.getString("description");

arr.add(new Model(title, desc));
}
```

but instead of getting the whole list, I get only first element... parsed values look like:

```
Title:  title1
Desc: desc1
```

So, I cant read the whole array, help me.

Comment: try arr.add(new Model(title,desc))..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse JSONArray in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android)

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Typing error here, I wrote it myself didn't copied it, I know how to use it

Comment: @ADM No, it has different JSON code, I have no problem with code like it, but as you can see, i have no array name

Comment: check my answer @George

Answer (score 2):

Try this, You might have a problem when you are using the JSON array line

```
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                ArrayList<Model> arr = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

           String title = 
                  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                 String description= 
                 jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");

                 arr.add(new Model(title, description));
               }
```

This should work. Let me know after you implement this.

Comment: brother arr.add(new Model(title,desc))..?

Comment: new Model()?? whats that

Comment: you know what i wanted to say. now you have correct in your answer.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta Please note that I'm using StringBuilder.toString();

Answer (score 2):

Feed the JSONArray constructor the JSON string of objects

Change

```java
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(new 
    JSONObject(jsonString).getJSONArray(jsonString);
```

To

```java
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting issue with parsing your string with

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(new JSONObject(jStrArr).getJSONArray(jStrArr));
```

So, I just tried your json string in my project and did some minor changes in the code. It's working fine now. I have added your json string in static variable for test as below.

```
String jStrArr = "[{\"title\" : \"title1\", \"description\" : \"desc1\" }, { \"title\" : \"title2\", \"description\" : \"desc2\" }]";

ArrayList<Model> listModel = new ArrayList<>();

try {

    JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jStrArr);

    for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jArr.getString(i));

        String title = jObj.getString("title");
        String desc = jObj.getString("description");

        listModel.add(new Model(title, desc));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So now while i debug the code, i got both json data in Array List. Please check below output.

[image]

**Note:** I have prepared this code based on your json string only. If you have a Json Object as a parent of this Json Array then there might be minor changes.