# Convert JSONArray to String[] Array

Tags: java, arrays

i have some problem Like This ..

```
["IMG-20181223-WA0010.jpg","IMG-20181225-WA0013.jpg","IMG-20181229-WA0001.jpg"]
```

How To convert JSONArray like that from real array in java ??
Sorry Bad English ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android how to convert json array to string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356231/android-how-to-convert-json-array-to-string-array)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array

Comment: you mean you have `JSONArray` and need to convert it to `String[]`? is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes Bro @Deadpool ..

Comment: can you show the code that you tried and also which library are you using? @ArjunNurdin

Comment: ok `import dev.x01.gz.kasir.Model.ItemBarang;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;`

Like this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm put the `JSONArray` to the string `toString()`, and i'm convert by regular expression like this ..

```
public String getImg(String d){
    return rubahFormat(d).split(",");
}

public String rubahFormat(String d){
    return d.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\\"]","");
}
```

Thx ..

Comment: thx, regex solved my problem two years ago ... btw makasih loh

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] stringArray = new String[jsonArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    stringArray[i]= (String)jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

`jsonArray` is your JSON object and `stringArray` variable will store as string array type

Comment: You've sized the output array based on the input `String[]` which the OP doesn't have.

Comment: Same sir error line 3
`(String)jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)`

Comment: Did you add `import org.json.JSONArray;` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this and it will help you

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

public class JsonArraytoArray {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    public void convertJsonarrtoArray() {
        jsonArray.add("java");
        jsonArray.add("test");
        jsonArray.add("work");
        String[] stringArray = new String[jsonArray.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            stringArray[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
        }
        System.out.println("stringArray  " + stringArray.length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonArraytoArray d = new JsonArraytoArray();
        d.convertJsonarrtoArray();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Streams to do that for you:

```
    String[] data = new String[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
    String jsonArray = "[\"" + Stream.of(data).collect(Collectors.joining("\", \"")) + "\"]";
```

The steam collector adds the `", "` between two values. Now simply add the `["` at the beginning, and the corresponding end.