# Java Convert this string to JSONArray

Tags: java, json, string, converters, arrays

I am getting the following `String` response from a server:

```
{"fid":"1272","uri":"http://someurl/services/file/1272"}
```

I need to convert it into a `JSONArray`. Any help?

By the way, I tried this and it does not work:

```
String response=getResponseFromServer();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
```

I get the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"fid":"1272","uri":"http://someurl/services/file/1272"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you using a JSON Library?

Comment: THis is a JSON **OBJECT**, not a JSON array

Comment: It is a Java String, not a JSON object yet. He's doing Java, not Javascript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're talking about using the [JSON in java](http://json.org/java/) library, then since your input string is a JSON object, not a JSON array, you should first load it using JSONObject:

```
String response=getResponseFromServer();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

After that, you can use [toJSONArray()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toJSONArray%28org.json.JSONArray%29) to convert a JSONObject to JSONArray given an array of key strings:

```
String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.toJSONArray(new JSONArray(names));
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. `JSONObject` was new to me.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. That's what stackoverflow for :)

Answer (score 5):

If you do a search right here on StackOverflow for **Java String to JSONArray**, you should get this answer: [Converting from JSONArray to String then back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983932/converting-from-jsonarray-to-string-then-back-again)

```
JSONArray jArray;
String s = jArray.toString(); // basically what you have ;)
JSONArray newJArray = new JSONArray(s);
```

Comment: The string I have is not in the format that the `JSONArray` constructor accepts.

Comment: Ok, so see @keelar's answer in that case.

Comment: The OP does not have `JSONArray` yet, and the JSON string in the question represents a `JSONObject` rather than a `JSONArray`.