# How to parse a JSON Array Object?

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm trying to get a JSON array for `ListView` on Android, but I couldn't so far.

My JSON is like this

```
[
   {
      "iD":1,
      "name":"name1"
   },
   {
      "iD":2,
      "name":"name2"
   },
   {
      "iD":3,
      "name":"name3"
   },
   {
      "iD":4,
      "name":"name4"
   }
]
```

Also Try tried this second JSON format

```
{
   "userdata":[
      {
         "iD":1,
         "name":"name1"
      },
      {
         "iD":2,
         "name":"name2"
      },
      {
         "iD":3,
         "name":"name3"
      },
      {
         "iD":4,
         "name":"name4"
      }
   ]
}
```

And my Java looks like

```
     private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
            Log.e("log1 = ", json);

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            Log.e("log2 = ","5" );  //Integer.toString(jsonArray.length())
            String[] heroes = new String[jsonArray.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

     private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        Log.e("result 2 = ", json);

        JSONObject entries = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = entries.getJSONArray("userdata");

        Log.e("length = ","5" );  //Integer.toString(jsonArray.length())
        String[] heroes = new String[jsonArray.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

I see the first log, but I can't see second. Also, I can't get the names for `ListView`.

```
require_once('connection.php');

$heroes = array(); 
$sql = "SELECT iD, name FROM valTable;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $name);

while($stmt->fetch()){

    $temp = [
        'iD'=>$id,
        'name'=>$name
    ];

    array_push($heroes, $temp);
}

echo json_encode($heroes);
```

Comment: What is printed in log 1?

Comment: @Athira  [{"iD":1,"name":"name1"},{"iD":2,"name":"name2"},{"iD":3,"name":"name3"},{"iD":4,"name":"name4"}] I see my JSON string no problem on log1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android)

Comment: what is your error? Please share your error.

Comment: I am still searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a JSON library such as [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse those objects for your.

Add on your gradle dependencies

```
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

You can create objects like

```
data class JsonRootObject(val userdata: List<User>)

data class User(val iD:Int, val name:String)
```

And then parse your object

```
val myParsedObject = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonRootObject::class.java);
```

Make sure that your field names are the same as your object being parsed, this also means case sensitive. If you want to change their mapping name you might want to use `@SerializedName("id")` annotation like

```
class User {

  @SerializedName("id")
  lateinit var id: Int

  @SerializedName("my_name")
  lateinit var name: String  

}
```

Consider this answer to your second object

```
{
   "userdata":[
      {
         "iD":1,
         "name":"name1"
      },
      {
         "iD":2,
         "name":"name2"
      },
      {
         "iD":3,
         "name":"name3"
      },
      {
         "iD":4,
         "name":"name4"
      }
   ]
}
```

and of course, all this is written in Kotlin.

Comment: Is it possible to give this example in Java?

Comment: You have a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android

Comment: Here is an example in Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/23862104/1573036 - Whenever asking a question on stack overflow, make sure that it does not exist one already.

Comment: Not success on your both links. The first one is same as mine but I cant understand where is my fault. It seems to ben at JSON array but check my php. I still cant see.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch instead of throws

```
    try {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        Log.e("log2 = ", "5");  //Integer.toString(jsonArray.length())
        String[] heroes = new String[jsonArray.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");
        }
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log3 = ", ""+e);
    }
```

Comment: I get This on log3 org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Check what you have in json, issue must be there in json

Comment: [{"iD":1,"name":"name1"},{"iD":2,"name":"name2"},{"iD":3,"name":"name3"},{"iD":4,"name":"name4"}] is there any thing wrong?

Comment: Add the part where you get json

Answer (score 0):

Try first to convert your `String json` to `JSONObject` and then convert that `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17012254/1595442).

Comment: I cant understand getNames function on that page. I think it is not included in JSON library

Comment: What is name of the json library you use?

Comment: import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;